# Trying to decrypt a sha256 hash

Tags: php, encryption

Please I need your help, Here is my encryption codes in PHP, it works fine but I don't know how to decrypt it in PHP. I need to get the actual value back. I have similar code in c# and I was able to get the same results. But I need to decrypt the value.

```
<?php 

$DATA= 'james' ;
$KEY= 'moveme'; 

$hash = hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($DATA), utf8_encode($KEY), false); 

echo $hash; 

?>
```

Comment: hash_hmac is one way hash like md5 u cant decrypt it

Answer (score 16):

hash_hmac is a hashing function, not an encryption function.  You won't be able to decrypt it.

You should use the [Mcrypt module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [SHA-256 hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions#SHA-2_family)  is a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), it is not [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). You cannot get your value back, neither in PHP nor in C#. Would be interesting to see this "working" C# code.

Comment: Here is another question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244796/encryption-and-decryption-that-work-for-both-c-and-php

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to encrypt and decrypt information, read up on the mcrypt functions.