# encryption and decryption that work for both c# and php

Tags: c#, php, encryption

Is there any encryption  and decryption  Algorithms that work for both php and c#? Please I need a sample codes

Comment: All algorithms work with all programming languages, there is loads of code using various libraries out there on the net

Comment: Quite a few duplicate/related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=encryption+java+c%23

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is DES3 encoding which can work fairly easily between C# and PHP.  Check out these two links for code examples.

**C# Example:**

http://www.csharper.net/blog/library_encrypt_and_decrypt_methods_using_tripledes_and_md5.aspx

**PHP Example**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

Comment: AES (Rijndael) would be a better choice.

Comment: thanks Shane are you saying this will work with both c# and php? C# sample codes is fine I am c# developer but I don't know which one to use in PHP sample codes.

Comment: Did I need a special library to run php on windows vista environment. I can write simple message like echo "hello" but whenever I try to run any these scripts no error nothing display on the page http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php. I'm new to PHP please help

Comment: @james - What environment are you running on Windows Vista?  If you aren't using it I highly suggest using XAMPP (I use this extensively for my windows development environment).  I have never had a problem with encryption routines using XAMPP.